# Find parametric equation of path of particle if acted on by force $\mu y^{-2}$ parallel to $y$-axis

Tags: integration

A particle is acted on by a force parallel to $y$-axis whose acceleration (always towards the $x$-axis) is $\mu y^{-2}$ and whenn $y=a$, it is projected parallel to the $x$-axis with velocity $\sqrt\frac{2\mu}{a}$. Find the parametric equation of the path of the particle. Here $\mu$ is a constant.

Since there is no acceleration along $x$-axis; $x=\sqrt\frac{2\mu}{a}t$

Now for $y$; I proceeded with $v\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{-\mu}{y^2}$

I got $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{a}}}=\sqrt{2\mu}t$

I am having trouble integrating this. I am unable to obtain $y$ in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{2\mu}\:t=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{a}}}=\int\sqrt{\frac{ay}{a-y}}dy$$
Change of variable :$\quad y=a \sin^2(Y)\quad$ leading to :
$$\sqrt{2\mu}\:t=2a^{3/2}\int \sin^2(Y)dY = a^{3/2}\left(Y-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2Y )\right)+\text{constant}$$
$Y=\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{\frac{y}{a}})\quad$ After simplification : 
$$t(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\mu}}\left( a^{3/2}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{a}}\right)-\sqrt{ay(a-y)} \right)+C$$

Do not try to express the inverse function $y(t)$ as a combination of a finite number of standard functions. There is no convenient special function available for a closed form. Use numerical calculus to compute or draw $y(t)$ .

A parametric form:
$$\begin{cases}
t = \frac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\mu}}\left(Y-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2Y )\right)+c \\
y=a\sin^2(Y)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the substitution of variables. I couldn't have come up with that. But, how do I express path of the particle in parametric form as the question demands. Is it ok to leave it in this form?

Comment: See the addition to the main answer :  $Y$ can be considered as the parameter of the wanted form of solution.

Comment: But in the parametric form can $Y$ be taken as the parameter when it is itself a function of $y$?

Comment: At first place, $Y$ is not defined as function od $y$. On the contrary $y$ is defined as a function of $Y$. Moreover, in the parametric form $Y$ is a dummy variable. Doesn't mater the symbol used. For example, if you prefer : $$\begin{cases}
t = \frac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\mu}}\left(\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)\right)+c \\
y=a\sin^2(\theta)
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The question demands for a parametric equation for the path which I think means a parameter, say $z$, should be found in both equations of $x(z)$ and $y(z)$

Comment: $$x=\sqrt\frac{2\mu}{a}t  \qquad\to\qquad x = a\left(\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta )\right)+c$$ Replace $\theta$ by $z$ if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I am currently stuck on this question. I have few basic questions.  Please clarify if possible.
1. Why is $ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}= 0 $ if the acceleration is always in direction of x-axis? Isn't $ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} $ = acceleration in x-axis direction ?

2. Why is negative value used here ? $ v\frac{dv}{dy}=\frac{-\mu}{y^2} $ . How did we learn that this is in the direction of y-decreasing?

Comment: "acceleration" is not a mathematical word. Please reformulate your question on a purely mathematical form. I guess that your difficulty doesn't come from the mathematical solving but comes from the physical modeling. It might be better to refer to physical tags than the tag "integration" or to raise the question on a physical forum.